# Understanding packed_trx

Tags: rpc, api

I have a problem with pushing transaction on blockchain, I think the problem is with the serialization of packed_trx. There is not enough info about it. So basically I took this JSON object below and converted it into hex.

```
{
  "compression": "none",
  "transaction": {
    "expiration": "2018-12-13T14:07:32",
    "ref_block_num": 32055469,
    "ref_block_prefix": 1753012779,
    "context_free_actions": [],
    "actions": [
        {
            "account": "decentwitter",
            "name": "tweet",
            "authorization": [
                {
                    "actor": "ysignchatapp",
                    "permission": "active"
                }
            ],
            "data": "0000000000ea305500000000487a2b9d102700000000000004454f53000000001163726561746564206279206e6f70726f6d"
        }
    ],
    "transaction_extensions": []
  },
  "signatures": [
        "...my signature..."
   ]
}
```

Is this right way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

### Updated Answer for producing Transaction:

From the eosjs docs:

https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs

You would hard code a key for dev purposes like so:

```
const defaultPrivateKey = "5JtUScZK2XEp3g9gh7F8bwtPTRAkASmNrrftmx4AxDKD5K4zDnr"; // useraaaaaaaa
const signatureProvider = new JsSignatureProvider([defaultPrivateKey]);
```

You would define a transaction like this:

```
(async () => {
  const result = await api.transact({
    actions: [{
      account: 'eosio.token',
      name: 'transfer',
      authorization: [{
        actor: 'useraaaaaaaa',
        permission: 'active',
      }],
      data: {
        from: 'useraaaaaaaa',
        to: 'useraaaaaaab',
        quantity: '0.0001 SYS',
        memo: '',
      },
    }]
  }, {
    blocksBehind: 3,
    expireSeconds: 30,
  });
  console.dir(result);
})();
```

And the API will handle producing the transaction with the signature that is compatible with the RPC API.

I have an example of how I integrated with Scatter if you would like an example of that: https://github.com/NatPDeveloper/eos-permission-viewer/blob/test/src/components/navigation.js#L77

---

Here's an example of how to create the json for a transaction then send that json file with `cleos push transaction`

---

Start with `cleos` by creating the json for each action, as follows (example uses transfer):

```
cleos [whatever logic for actions your trying to send here] -s -d -j
```

Flags:

```
-s,--skip-sign              Specify if unlocked wallet keys should be used to sign transaction
-d,--dont-broadcast         don't broadcast transaction to the network (just print to stdout)
-j,--json                   print result as json
```

This creates json output do this for all the transactions:

```
{
  "expiration": "2018-10-20T10:54:37",
    "ref_block_num": 92,
    "ref_block_prefix": 276911189,
    "max_net_usage_words": 0,
    "max_cpu_usage_ms": 0,
    "delay_sec": 0,
    "context_free_actions": [],
    "actions": [{
      "account": "eosio.token",
      "name": "transfer",
      "authorization": [{
        "actor": "fromaccount",
        "permission": "active"
      }
      ],
      "data": "00f2d4142123e95d0040c85353840ccd102700000000000004454f5300000000046d656d6f"
    }
    ],
    "transaction_extensions": [],
    "signatures": [],
    "context_free_data": []
}

{
  "expiration": "2018-10-20T10:54:42",
    "ref_block_num": 102,
    "ref_block_prefix": 3271438144,
    "max_net_usage_words": 0,
    "max_cpu_usage_ms": 0,
    "delay_sec": 0,
    "context_free_actions": [],
    "actions": [{
      "account": "eosio.token",
      "name": "transfer",
      "authorization": [{
        "actor": "fromaccount",
        "permission": "active"
      }
      ],
      "data": "00f2d4142123e95d0080c85353840ccd102700000000000004454f5300000000046d656d6f"
    }
    ],
    "transaction_extensions": [],
    "signatures": [],
    "context_free_data": []
}

{
  "expiration": "2018-10-20T10:54:45",
    "ref_block_num": 109,
    "ref_block_prefix": 718898287,
    "max_net_usage_words": 0,
    "max_cpu_usage_ms": 0,
    "delay_sec": 0,
    "context_free_actions": [],
    "actions": [{
      "account": "eosio.token",
      "name": "transfer",
      "authorization": [{
        "actor": "fromaccount",
        "permission": "active"
      }
      ],
      "data": "00f2d4142123e95d00c0c85353840ccd102700000000000004454f5300000000046d656d6f"
    }
    ],
    "transaction_extensions": [],
    "signatures": [],
    "context_free_data": []
}
```

To make this into one transaction, copy and paste each of the **actions** (an array of actions) into the first json output, like so:

```
{
  "expiration": "2018-10-20T10:54:37",
    "ref_block_num": 92,
    "ref_block_prefix": 276911189,
    "max_net_usage_words": 0,
    "max_cpu_usage_ms": 0,
    "delay_sec": 0,
    "context_free_actions": [],
    "actions": [{
      "account": "eosio.token",
      "name": "transfer",
      "authorization": [{
        "actor": "fromaccount",
        "permission": "active"
      }
      ],
      "data": "00f2d4142123e95d0040c85353840ccd102700000000000004454f5300000000046d656d6f"
    },{
      "account": "eosio.token",
      "name": "transfer",
      "authorization": [{
        "actor": "fromaccount",
        "permission": "active"
      }
      ],
      "data": "00f2d4142123e95d0080c85353840ccd102700000000000004454f5300000000046d656d6f"
    },{
      "account": "eosio.token",
      "name": "transfer",
      "authorization": [{
        "actor": "fromaccount",
        "permission": "active"
      }
      ],
      "data": "00f2d4142123e95d00c0c85353840ccd102700000000000004454f5300000000046d656d6f"
    }
    ],
    "transaction_extensions": [],
    "signatures": [],
    "context_free_data": []
}
```

Finally, save this json file, and execute it as follows (be sure wallet is open and unlocked):

```
cleos push transaction ./test.json
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think that is not what I needed.
I am trying to make the android wallet, which communicates through API directly without cleos. So what I need is exact algorithm how is `data` generated and how to send that JSON to /push_transaction.

Comment: Ah okay. You don't want to handle that logic yourself, use eosjs for that.  I've updated my answer.